# Xamarin Cam2 IOnImageAvailableListener's OnImageAvailable called twice causing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera2

UPDATE: The initial question has been answered as to why the crashes happen but the lingering problem remains of why is the 'OnImageAvailable' callback called so may times? When it is called, I want to do stuff with the image, but whatever method I run at that time is called many times. Is this the wrong place to be using the resulting image?

> ---

I am using the sample code found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Camera2Basic/) for a Xamarin Android implementation of the Android Camera2 API. My issue is that when the capture button is pressed a single time, the `OnCameraAvalibleListener`'s `OnImageAvailable` callback gets called multiple times.

This is causing a problem because the image from `AcquireNextImage` needs to be closed before another can be used, but close is not called until the `Run` method of the `ImageSaver` class as seen below.

This causes these 2 errors:

> Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire
>   more than maxImages buffers

AND

> maxImages (2) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring
>   more.

The max image is set to 2 by default, but setting it to 1 does not help. How do I prevent the callback from being called twice?

```
public void OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
    {
        var image = reader.AcquireNextImage();
        owner.mBackgroundHandler.Post(new ImageSaver(image, file));
    }

    // Saves a JPEG {@link Image} into the specified {@link File}.
    private class ImageSaver : Java.Lang.Object, IRunnable
    {
        // The JPEG image
        private Image mImage;

        // The file we save the image into.
        private File mFile;

        public ImageSaver(Image image, File file)
        {
            if (image == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("image");
            if (file == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("file");

            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
            buffer.Get(bytes);
            using (var output = new FileOutputStream(mFile))
            {
                try
                {
                    output.Write(bytes);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.PrintStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    mImage.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `OnImageAvailable` can be called again as soon as you leave it if there is another picture in the pipeline.

I would recommend calling `Close` in the same method you are calling  `AcquireNextImage`. So, if you choose to get the image directly from that callback, then you have to call `Close` in there as well.

One solution involved grabbing the image in that method and close it right away.

```
public void OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
{
    var image = reader.AcquireNextImage();

    try
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
        buffer.Get(bytes);

        // I am not sure where you get the file instance but it is not important.
        owner.mBackgroundHandler.Post(new ImageSaver(bytes, file));
    }
    finally
    {
        image.Close();
    }
}
```

The `ImageSaver` would be modified to accept the byte array as first parameter in the constructor:

```
public ImageSaver(byte[] bytes, File file)
{
    if (bytes == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("bytes");
    if (file == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("file");

    mBytes = bytes;
    mFile = file;
}
```

The major downside of this solution is the risk of putting a lot of pressure on the memory as you basically save the images in memory until they are processed, one after another.

Another solution consists in acquiring the image on the background thread instead.

```
public void OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
{
    // Again, I am not sure where you get the file instance but it is not important.
    owner.mBackgroundHandler.Post(new ImageSaver(reader, file));
}
```

This solution is less intensive on the memory; but you might have to increase the maximum number of images from 2 to something higher depending on your needs. Again, the `ImageSaver`'s constructor needs to be modified to accept an `ImageReader` as a parameter:

```
public ImageSaver(ImageReader imageReader, File file)
{
    if (imageReader == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("imageReader");
    if (file == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("file");

    mImageReader = imageReader;
    mFile = file;
}
```

Now the `Run` method would have the responsibility of acquiring and releasing the Image:

```
public void Run()
{
    Image image = mImageReader.AcquireNextImage();

    try
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
        buffer.Get(bytes);

        using (var output = new FileOutputStream(mFile))
        {
            try
            {
                output.Write(bytes);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        image?.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very excellent answer Kzrystof. Thank you. Please note the follow on question.

Comment: @Sevren As long as there is a new image available, the callback method will be called by the [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener).

Comment: Ok, so after it has written many images to disk in the same file, where can I simply get the one single picture that I need? If it is saved to disk, where is the call back that says "Ok, I'm all done, use this image"? I am really frustrated with this ridicules API and all of the total nonsense that I have to go through just to get a single photo.

Comment: @Sevren If you just want a still picture, you may want to look into the file [CameraCaptureStillPictureSessionCallback.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic/Camera2Basic/Listeners/CameraCaptureStillPictureSessionCallback.cs).

Comment: That is the one I thought to use as well, but it also gets called a large number of times, like 10 or 15, every time a photo is taken.

Comment: @Sevren I think that this one deserves its own question on SO ... I am convinced that this callback is not expected to be called that once each time a picture is taken. Maybe there is something wrong with the subscription... something like registering the same callback several times to the different instances...

Comment: @Sevren did you ever figure out the solution to the issue of multiple images being saved?

Comment: No I never did.

Answer (score 0):

I too facing this issue for longer time and tried implementing @kzrytof's solution but didn't helped well as expected but found the way to get the onImageAvailable to execute once.,

Scenario: When the image is available then the onImageAvailable method is called right?
**so, What I did is after closing the image using image.close(); I called the imagereader.setonImageAvailableListener() and made the listener = null. this way I stopped the execution for second time.,**

I know, *that your question is for xamarin and my below code is in native android java but the method and functionalities are same, so try once:*

```
@Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            final Image image=imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        try {
            if (image != null) {
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
                int bitmapWidth = width + rowPadding / pixelStride;

                if (latestBitmap == null ||
                        latestBitmap.getWidth() != bitmapWidth ||
                        latestBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
                    if (latestBitmap != null) {
                        latestBitmap.recycle();
                    }

                  }

                latestBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
            }
        }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
            finally{
                image.close();
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, svc.getHandler());
            }
    // next steps to save the image
}
```